# Integration : $\int\frac{\sin^2x\cos^2x}{(\sin^3x+\cos^3x)^2}{\rm d}x$

Tags: integration

Try an interesting integration problem:

> $$\int\frac{\sin^2x\cos^2x}{(\sin^3x+\cos^3x)^2}{\rm d}x$$

I know the solution which almost took me 15 minutes. Good Luck!

Comment: This [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int+sin%28x%29%5E2cos%28x%29%5E2%2F%28sin%28x%29%5E3%2Bcos%28x%29%5E3%29%5E2) took me only $2$ minutes.

Comment: @Elaqqad check the link again.

Comment: It's not a good idea (using always mathematica) but it's the first thing i do when i was given a hazardous calculus, I'm an addict! so much respect for you you don't use them.

Comment: @Elaqqad it sometimes gives wierd forms. In this case too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

take the $\cos^3x$ common from denominator outside , you will get $$\frac{\tan^2x\sec^2x}{(\tan^3x+1)^2}$$ now take $t=\tan^3x+1$ thus $dt=3\tan^2x\sec^2x$ thus easily solvable

> $$\int\frac{\sin^2x\cos^2x}{(\sin^3x+\cos^3x)^2}{\rm d}x=-\frac13\frac1{1+\tan^3x}+c$$

Comment: Yes correct....Bravo

Comment: @avz2611  Did you do the "trick" at first glance? It always takes me a lot of time dealing with such problems.

Comment: not at the first glance , i had a different idea the first time , but i did get it at the second attempt, these kind of problems might be first trick for one but take 15 mins for other but it can easily be vice versa

Comment: this is a good answer to an interesting question. To keep it here, someone should add a post to the [Reopening Thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio) lest it be deleted.